# Ansible a task to check connectivity with windows machine

Tags: windows, jenkins, ansible

I have a Jenkinsfile pipeline that's composed of the following primary steps:

- **reverting** the machine to a clean snapshot
- **copying files** to each machine from a JFrog repository

The `copy_jfrog_builds` playbook is composed of several task, each task downloads a particular file to a machine

When the first task is started I see in the log the following error:

```
TASK [artifactory : download_server.msi] ***************************************

fatal: [vm1.domain.com]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "ntlm: HTTPConnectionPool(host='vm1.domain
.com', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.H
TTPConnection object at 0x7f7146aed460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
'))", "unreachable": true}

...ignoring
```

The funny thing is that when jenkins is continued to other stages and steps on this 'UNREACHABLE' machine, I don't get this error anymore, meaning that maybe this state is a temporary state...

I tried different ways to overcome this error but without success. Below some examples:

- Adding `retries` and `delay` keys

```yaml
- name: download_server.msi
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      # TO-DO 
  become: true
  become_method: runas
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
  register: result
  retries: 5
  delay: 30
  until: result is not failed
```

- Then I thought about `win_wait_for` option as a pre-task before I'm starting to copy files to the machines

```yaml
- name: Wait for port 5985 to become open on the host
  ansible.builtin.wait_for:
    port: 5985
    delay: 10
    state: started
```

- Then I thought about `win_ping` option as a pre-task before I'm starting to copy files to the machines and wrap the `win_ping` task with a retry mechanism till I get `pong` result. but it was failed with same error at the start.

```yaml
- name: win_ping 
  ansible.windows.win_ping:
```

- Then I tried was the `async` option that also failed

```yaml
- name: download_server.msi
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      # TO-DO 
  become: true
  become_method: runas
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
  register: result
  async: 10
  poll: 3
  until: result is not failed
```

- The last thing I tried was adding `gather_timeout = 300` to `ansble.cfg` file. Gather fact still failed on:

```
PLAY [revert vmware vcenter lab] ***********************************************

redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.setup to ansible.windows.setup

Using module file /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/ansible/windows/plugins/modules/setup.ps1

Pipelining is enabled.

<vm1.domain> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: domain\user on PORT 5985 TO vm1.domain



TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************

task path: /product/ansible/playbooks/revert_vcenter_lab.yml:2

fatal: [vm1.domain]: UNREACHABLE! => {

    "changed": false,

    "msg": "ntlm: HTTPConnectionPool(host='vm1.domain', port=5985): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f6fb469f7c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))",

    "unreachable": true

}
```

How can I make sure a connection is established and I can copy without any doubts?

Comment: can you explain why you solutions didn't work (especially the first)?
jenkins will continue as long as ansible continues, and ansible continues because you must have an "ignore_errors: true" somewhere, or a failed_when parameter.

Comment: @The_Pingu The first solution is failed I think it because of the ```gathering facts``` phase. meaning ansible cannot connect to the machine and gather facts. I did not include ```"ignore_errors: true"``` in the copy_files nor revert_vms playbooks because they are critical to the continuation of the process of installing the product.